# how does gcc -c option work?

Tags: c, gcc

```
#include"header.h"

int main(){

    function();
    return 0;
}
```

above is simplified form of my code. I implemented function() in header.h file, and put it in the same directory with this code.c file.

I heard that "gcc -c code.c" is "compile but no linking" option, but this code need linking with header.h file. So I guess -c option will flag an error, while it didn't. Though, without -c option it flags an error. Can anyone explain how this -c options works?

Comment: I think you're confused about how header files work and what compilation and linking actually are. Headers just declare prototypes (essentially promises that the function will actually exist in the future). The linker takes these promises, takes in bits of compiled code and tries its best to fulfill them. If you were to try to actually link this, *then* you would get an error. Under linux, the linker is typically `ld` if you want to call it directly, or you can try with gcc like `gcc -o program obj.o` and see your error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Header files have nothing to do with linking. Linking is combining multiple object files and libraries into an executable.

Header files are processed by the compiler, as part of generating an object file. Therefore, `gcc -c` will process header files.

Answer (score 1):

gcc -c compiles source files without linking.

header files have nothing to do with linking process, they are only used in compilation process to tell compiler the various declaration and function prototypes.

However it is bad practice to implement function in header file, both compilation strategy should work in this case. i.e. gcc with and without c flag

Comment: Any reason for why you have formatted the answer as code?

Comment: Also it doesn't look that this answer add something substantial to the answer that already had been given 2 hours before.

Comment: emphasis was on "it should compile successfully whether -c flag is used or not"